# Send JS variable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I would take the value using getElementById() and pass to a variable on PHP.

```
<script>
function addMachine() {
  var ip = document.getElementById('ipTextBox').value;
  document.getElementById('ipTextBox').submit;
}
<\script>
```

The HTML looks like that

```
<div class="container">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addMachine">
     <div class="modal fade" id="addMachine" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add new machine</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label>Insert machine IP<input id="ipTextBox"></input></label>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="addMachine()">ADD</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<\div>
```

I don't have any ideas on how to pass this to a PHP variable.

Comment: Are you trying to pass it to a `php` page? can you include the code of  it also?

Comment: There is two ways for this. Ajax, or form POST. Choose the better one

Comment: If you want to take user input, hit submit, and have that sent to PHP, the straight forward solution is using a [form](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: Yes, im trying but i'm don't have any idea how to pass this to a php page, basically i don't have any php code.

Comment: Like @Superdrac said, there are two solutions: with POST however you won't be using JS and the page will have to reload, or with AJAX, no page reload. I have included the latter in my answer bellow.

Comment: @Ivan can you show me how to do this using POST?

Comment: sure, I'll edit my post

Comment: Ok, I have added a second section. Keep in mind that you're not actually making a form for the user to fill in so the second method is not a good idea in my opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP is a backend language used to render HTML and send it to the client on page load. And Javascript is a client side language. If you want to send variables from JS to PHP, basically sending information from the client to the server without page reload, you need to use AJAX:

> AJAX stands for "Asynchronous JavaScript and XML". Although the name includes XML, JSON is more often used due to it's simpler formatting and lower redundancy. AJAX allows the user to communicate with external resources without reloading the webpage.
>   Stackoverflow's documentation on Javascript AJAX

- **With AJAX**

I have made a post on the documentation page, here it is. I hope it helps you understand how it works.

This function runs an AJAX call using GET allowing us to send **parameters** (object) to a **file** (string) and launch a **callback** (function) when the request has been ended.

```
function ajax(file, params, callback) {

  var url = file + '?';

  // loop through object and assemble the url
  var notFirst = false;
  for (var key in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      url += (notFirst ? '&' : '') + key + "=" + params[key];
    }
    notFirst = true;
  }

  // create a AJAX call with url as parameter
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Here's how we use it:

```
ajax('cars.php', {type:"Volvo", model:"300", color:"purple"}, function(response) {
  // add here the code to be executed when data comes back to this page      
  // for example console.log(response) will show the AJAX response in console
});
```

And the following shows how to retreive the url parameters in `cars.php`:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['type'], $_REQUEST['model'], $_REQUEST['color'])) {
  // they are set, we can use them !
  $response = 'The color of your car is ' . $_REQUEST['color'] . '. ';
  $response .= 'It is a ' . $_REQUEST['type'] . ' model ' . $_REQUEST['model'] . '!';
  echo $response;
}
```

If you had `console.log(response)` in callback function the result in console would have been:

> The color of your car is purple. It is a Volvo model 300!

- **With a HTML form**

In your HTML page you will have to include a form

```
<form action="get_data.php" method="get">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And in `get_data.php` (the target file) you'll have to write:

```
<?php
echo $_GET["name"];
echo $_GET["email"];
```

This second method however will redirect the user to `get_data.php`, I personnaly don't really like it and prefer AJAX for its efficiency.